# How to get a child's position within an ExpandableList in Android relative to the entire list?

Tags: android, list, hashmap, expandablelistview

i have a list like this:

```
-ONE
-TWO
-THREE
```

when expanded:

```
-ONE
 ->a1
-TWO
 ->a2
 ->b2
-THREE
 ->a3
```

**What I would like:**

I want a child's position within the entire list like this, doesn't matter if other groups are expanded or not:

```
a1=0
a2=1
b2=2
etc...
```

**What have i tried so far:**
 `int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);`

This only gives me the child's position within the group. so,

```
a1=0

a2=0
b2=1
etc...
```

I also looked into `getFlatListPosition`, but the way it works is that a child's position will only be counted relative to the list if the groups are expanded. And it also counts the group's position. eg if ONE is not expanded and TWO and THREE are expanded then:

```
-ONE
-TWO = 0
 ->a2 = 1
 ->b2 = 2
-THREE = 3
 ->a3 = 4
```

**Alternatives:**
i could use hash mapping, but would like to see if there is a built in way:)

**Why do i want child's pos:**

I have mapped the child's position within the list to it's corresponding id in the database. So when a user wants to delete child, i can just look it up in the hashmap and pass it's id over to the database remove function.

Comment: What sort of adapter are you using to populate the `ExpandableListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Lastly, i found solution. in your Onclick, add the following code:

```
int size = 0;
int mpos;
for (int m = 0; m < groupPosition; m++) {
  size += menuAdapter.getChildrenCount(m);
}
mpos = childPosition + size;
```

So, `mpos` will be the position of child value within the whole list.